# Unable to request with refreshed Token Retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

I'm using a Interceptor to refresh my expired Token. After refreshing I'm trying to send the original request with the new refreshed token. But I'm unable to send the request with the new Token.

If the Token is Valid. App is working fine. But when the Token is INVALID. I think the network request in fragment is ahead of the refresh token request...

Please guide me...

**INTERCEPTOR**

```
public class HttpInterceptor implements Interceptor {

@Override
public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Request request = chain.request();

    //Build new request
    Request.Builder builder = request.newBuilder();
    builder.header("Accept", "application/json"); //if necessary, say to consume JSON

    String token = PrefUtils.getAppToken(HelloApplication.getContext()); //save token of this request for future
    setAuthHeader(builder, token); //write current token to request

    request = builder.build(); //overwrite old request
    Response response = chain.proceed(request); //perform request, here original request will be executed

    String body = response.peekBody(2048).string();
    try {
        APIStatus stat = new Gson().fromJson(body, APIStatus.class);
        Log.e("ARUL intercept: ", stat.getMessage());
        if (stat.getMessage().contains("Invalid Auth Token")) { //if unauthorized
            synchronized (this) { //perform all 401 in sync blocks, to avoid multiply token updates
                String currentToken = PrefUtils.getAppToken(HelloApplication.getContext()); //get currently stored token

                if (currentToken != null && currentToken.equals(token)) { //compare current token with token that was stored before, if it was not updated - do update

                    int code = refreshToken() / 100; //refresh token
                    if (code != 2) { //if refresh token failed for some reason
                        if (code == 4) //only if response is 400, 500 might mean that token was not updated
                            logout(); //go to login screen
                        return response; //if token refresh failed - show error to user
                    }
                }

                if (PrefUtils.getAppToken(HelloApplication.getContext()) != null) { //retry requires new auth token,
                    setAuthHeader(builder, PrefUtils.getAppToken(HelloApplication.getContext())); //set auth token to updated
                    request = builder.build();
                    return chain.proceed(request); //repeat request with new token
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IllegalStateException | JsonSyntaxException exception) {
        Log.e("ARUL intercept: ", "GOT VALID REPSONSE!!! ");
    }

    return response;
}

private void setAuthHeader(Request.Builder builder, String token) {
    if (token != null) //Add Auth token to each request if authorized
        builder.header("auth_token", token);
}

private int refreshToken() {
    //Refresh token, synchronously, save it, and return result code
    //you might use retrofit here
    int status = 2;
    HelloApi mHelloApi = ServiceGenerator.provideHelloService();

    HashMap<String, RequestBody> partMap = new HashMap<>();
    String ID = PrefUtils.getUserID(HelloApplication.getContext());
    partMap.put("user_id", Utils.createPartFromString(ID));

    Call<APIStatus> register = mHelloApi.requestAccessToken(partMap);

    APIStatus mAPI = register.execute().body();
    PrefUtils.updateToken(HelloApplication.getContext(), mAPI.getToken());

    return status;
}

private int logout() {
    //logout your user
    return 4;
}
```

}

**FRAGMENT**

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        mFactory = InjectorUtils.provideHomeFactory(getActivity());
        mViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this, mFactory).get(HomeViewModel.class);

        if (mUser != null) {
            Log.e("User EMAIL > ", mUser.getEmail());
            Log.e("User ID > ", mUser.getUserID() + " > > " + mUser.getTokenAuthentication());

            fetchDashboard();
        }
    }
    
    
    private void fetchDashboard() {

        partMap.put("user_id", Utils.createPartFromString(mUser.getUserID()));

        mViewModel.getSnickers(partMap).observe(getActivity(), apiResponse -> {
            if (apiResponse != null) {
                mProgress.hide();
                mDiscoverRVAdapter.setItems(apiResponse.getEntityStickers());
                mDiscoverRVAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
```

**LOGCAT**

```
2020-08-03 11:13:04.210 10708-10708/com.hello.helloapp E/User ID >: 70 > > %MoJCCdoVqrRipyYgFrCShBK#XX#jEhkebRWOUkUr#eRgOK
2020-08-03 11:13:04.231 10708-10734/com.hello.helloapp D/OkHttp: --> POST http://sandbox.hello.com/api/mapi/dashboard
2020-08-03 11:13:04.231 10708-10734/com.hello.helloapp D/OkHttp: Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=3676a142-4869-46e1-b525-a3bdc72fe4a5
2020-08-03 11:13:04.231 10708-10734/com.hello.helloapp D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 240
2020-08-03 11:13:04.232 10708-10734/com.hello.helloapp D/OkHttp: --3676a142-4869-46e1-b525-a3bdc72fe4a5
2020-08-03 11:13:04.232 10708-10734/com.hello.helloapp D/OkHttp: Content-Disposition: form-data; name="user_id"
2020-08-03 11:13:04.232 10708-10734/com.hello.helloapp D/OkHttp: Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
2020-08-03 11:13:04.232 10708-10734/com.hello.helloapp D/OkHttp: Content-Type: multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8
2020-08-03 11:13:04.232 10708-10734/com.hello.helloapp D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 2
2020-08-03 11:13:04.232 10708-10734/com.hello.helloapp D/OkHttp: 70
2020-08-03 11:13:04.232 10708-10734/com.hello.helloapp D/OkHttp: --3676a142-4869-46e1-b525-a3bdc72fe4a5--
2020-08-03 11:13:04.232 10708-10734/com.hello.helloapp D/OkHttp: --> END POST (240-byte body)
2020-08-03 11:13:04.238 10708-10734/com.hello.helloapp E/<HEADER>: Token Added > %MoJCCdoVqrRipyYgFrCShBK#XX#jEhkebRWOUkUr#eRgOK
2020-08-03 11:13:04.258 10708-10732/com.hello.helloapp I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2020-08-03 11:13:04.258 10708-10732/com.hello.helloapp D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
2020-08-03 11:13:04.259 10708-10732/com.hello.helloapp E/EGL_adreno: CreateContext rcMajorVersion:3, minorVersion:0
2020-08-03 11:13:04.272 10708-10732/com.hello.helloapp D/EGL_adreno: eglCreateContext: 0xb70052a0: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
2020-08-03 11:13:04.313 10708-10732/com.hello.helloapp E/EGL_adreno: tid 10732: eglSurfaceAttrib(1582): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
2020-08-03 11:13:04.313 10708-10732/com.hello.helloapp W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x9aa589e0, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
2020-08-03 11:13:04.685 10708-10734/com.hello.helloapp E/ARUL intercept:: Invalid Auth Token
2020-08-03 11:13:04.714 10708-10734/com.hello.helloapp E/Current Token: %MoJCCdoVqrRipyYgFrCShBK#XX#jEhkebRWOUkUr#eRgOK
2020-08-03 11:13:04.719 10708-10734/com.hello.helloapp E/userID: > >70
2020-08-03 11:13:04.722 10708-10734/com.hello.helloapp D/OkHttp: --> POST http://sandbox.hello.com/api/mapi/get_token
2020-08-03 11:13:04.722 10708-10734/com.hello.helloapp D/OkHttp: Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=810973ea-31be-4f2c-81c4-a7d57298d526
2020-08-03 11:13:04.722 10708-10734/com.hello.helloapp D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 240
2020-08-03 11:13:04.723 10708-10734/com.hello.helloapp D/OkHttp: --810973ea-31be-4f2c-81c4-a7d57298d526
2020-08-03 11:13:04.724 10708-10734/com.hello.helloapp D/OkHttp: Content-Disposition: form-data; name="user_id"
2020-08-03 11:13:04.724 10708-10734/com.hello.helloapp D/OkHttp: Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
2020-08-03 11:13:04.724 10708-10734/com.hello.helloapp D/OkHttp: Content-Type: multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8
2020-08-03 11:13:04.724 10708-10734/com.hello.helloapp D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 2
2020-08-03 11:13:04.724 10708-10734/com.hello.helloapp D/OkHttp: 70
2020-08-03 11:13:04.724 10708-10734/com.hello.helloapp D/OkHttp: --810973ea-31be-4f2c-81c4-a7d57298d526--
2020-08-03 11:13:04.724 10708-10734/com.hello.helloapp D/OkHttp: --> END POST (240-byte body)
2020-08-03 11:13:05.140 10708-10734/com.hello.helloapp D/OkHttp: <-- 200 OK http://sandbox.hello.com/api/mapi/get_token (415ms)
2020-08-03 11:13:05.140 10708-10734/com.hello.helloapp D/OkHttp: Connection: Keep-Alive
2020-08-03 11:13:05.140 10708-10734/com.hello.helloapp D/OkHttp: X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.29
2020-08-03 11:13:05.140 10708-10734/com.hello.helloapp D/OkHttp: Set-Cookie: ci_session=e06bfe493b4e0b656d5a2c5a7dfee86364307e78; expires=Mon, 03-Aug-2020 07:43:04 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; HttpOnly
2020-08-03 11:13:05.141 10708-10734/com.hello.helloapp D/OkHttp: Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
2020-08-03 11:13:05.141 10708-10734/com.hello.helloapp D/OkHttp: Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
2020-08-03 11:13:05.141 10708-10734/com.hello.helloapp D/OkHttp: Pragma: no-cache
2020-08-03 11:13:05.141 10708-10734/com.hello.helloapp D/OkHttp: Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
2020-08-03 11:13:05.141 10708-10734/com.hello.helloapp D/OkHttp: Vary: Accept-Encoding
2020-08-03 11:13:05.141 10708-10734/com.hello.helloapp D/OkHttp: Date: Mon, 03 Aug 2020 05:43:04 GMT
2020-08-03 11:13:05.141 10708-10734/com.hello.helloapp D/OkHttp: Server: LiteSpeed
2020-08-03 11:13:05.143 10708-10734/com.hello.helloapp D/OkHttp: {"message_code":1,"message":"Result found.","token_authentication":"UYCVHZkFKkMhqbR#tbZIOAboy%A#hvRVuecNC%mBjUBTk@H"}
2020-08-03 11:13:05.144 10708-10734/com.hello.helloapp D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (117-byte body)
2020-08-03 11:13:05.163 10708-10734/com.hello.helloapp D/OkHttp: <-- 200 OK http://sandbox.hello.com/api/mapi/dashboard (931ms)
2020-08-03 11:13:05.163 10708-10734/com.hello.helloapp D/OkHttp: Connection: Keep-Alive
2020-08-03 11:13:05.163 10708-10734/com.hello.helloapp D/OkHttp: X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.29
2020-08-03 11:13:05.163 10708-10734/com.hello.helloapp D/OkHttp: Set-Cookie: ci_session=c7d4a52827268f0f33fe51594fb0c314a21129a6; expires=Mon, 03-Aug-2020 07:43:04 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; HttpOnly
2020-08-03 11:13:05.164 10708-10734/com.hello.helloapp D/OkHttp: Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
2020-08-03 11:13:05.164 10708-10734/com.hello.helloapp D/OkHttp: Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
2020-08-03 11:13:05.164 10708-10734/com.hello.helloapp D/OkHttp: Pragma: no-cache
2020-08-03 11:13:05.164 10708-10734/com.hello.helloapp D/OkHttp: Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
2020-08-03 11:13:05.164 10708-10734/com.hello.helloapp D/OkHttp: Vary: Accept-Encoding
2020-08-03 11:13:05.164 10708-10734/com.hello.helloapp D/OkHttp: Date: Mon, 03 Aug 2020 05:43:04 GMT
2020-08-03 11:13:05.164 10708-10734/com.hello.helloapp D/OkHttp: Server: LiteSpeed
2020-08-03 11:13:05.165 10708-10734/com.hello.helloapp D/OkHttp: {"message_code":404,"message":"Invalid Auth Token","response":"Invalid Auth Token"}
2020-08-03 11:13:05.165 10708-10734/com.hello.helloapp D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (83-byte body)
2020-08-03 11:13:05.171 10708-10708/com.hello.helloapp D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
```

**UPDATE**

Refreshed Token is stored in shared Prefs successfully. But while retrying the original request. it is still using the old token ? How can I Fix it ?

Comment: I suggest making a simple reproduction and posting that, see http://sscce.org/
It's hard for others to help with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this issue is refreshToken() method. You are trying to make a async call which means retrofit will create another thread to execute refresh token api.

Instead of calling
`register.enqueue` which is async you should call

`register.execute`
this will make a synchronous call and this should be used from a background thread.
For example checkout this  [link](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-synchronous-and-asynchronous-requests)

Comment: Your suggestion was helpful. But While retrying the original request it is still attaching the old Token ? Please check the update....

Comment: @user3467240 Could you please add a log in setAuthHeader() method to confirm if we are indeed getting the new token from sharedPreferences.